# parsing a command from the terminal

Tags: ruby, parsing

I want to write a command in the terminal like `config.section.key`, parse the command, and get the strings `"section"` and `"key"`. I want to use these two keys in my function to search a hash.

Is there any way to parse a command from the terminal to do this?

Comment: This is really vague in terms of what you want in terms of concrete results. `"config.section.key".split('.')` gets you part-way there.

Comment: I just figured they where asking how to give system commands in Ruby

Comment: I have a hash of hash that has {"section"=>{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"} } structure. Now I wanna run a command config.section.key1 is the terminal and parse the command and send "section" & "key1" into my function so that I can use them as key and get result value1

Answer (score 2):

To execute terminal commands you can use either backticks or a system call here's some examples keep in mind that this is all pseudo code and I have no idea if this will run correctly:

```
def create_file
  `touch test.txt`
end

def cmd
  system('ls')
end

def check_file
  results = cmd
  if results.include?('test.txt')
    puts 'File exists.'
  else
    puts 'Creating file..'
    create_file
  end
end
```

Now to the parsing part, depending on what you want to do, you can either save the information into a variable, or you could use a regex to extract the information. So if you wanted to extract digits with a regex: `/\d+/` if you wanted to save the information: `results = cmd`..

I hope this answers your question.

To split the information, you could use the `split` method for example:

```
def cmd
  `prt_jobs`
end

def check_jobs
  res = cmd
  res.split(".")
end
```

This will split the results of a print jobs command by periods and make them into an array. I'd show you more except I'm on my phone so it will have to wait

Comment: I just wanna split it by (.)

Comment: this code gives following output: command.rb:11:in `check_file': undefined method `include?' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
 from command.rb:20:in `<main>'

Comment: That's pseudo code, use a different command. `prt_jobs` is more of a Linux thing anyways

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: I did it only                                                                                                                                   a = gets.chomp
 b = a.split(".")
 c = b[1]
 d = b[2]

Answer (score 1):

As Tadman commented, you can use the [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method to split the [`argv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) on period characters, if that is your desire:

`config, section, key, *rest = ARGF.argv.split('.')`

Another good option when dealing with parsing command lines is the Ruby standard library [`OptionParser`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) class. Rather than rebuild all of the CLI parsing by hand, the OptionParser class has that built in and much more. The resulting scripts can feel much more linux like and be familiar to anyone who's used bash before.